# Programmatically changing Keyboard works in Simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, internationalization, keyboard, ios-simulator

I am trying to change language of my application, mainly to display an Arabic keyboard on one query screen. 
In my Main program before call to UIApplicationMain I have this line:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar",@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

It successfully changes the language on iPhone Simulator but not on iPhone. On Simulator the keyboard is changed to Arabic but on iPhone it remains English, no matter what. I also have a remove statement before as well. The full code is:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar",@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: What versions of iOS are running on the simulator and on the device?

Comment: Simulator is what I believe comes with xCode (4.4). The device has 5.1 (latest).

Comment: Are you sure that the phone your are using has Arabic installed? There  is probably some way to check, google it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check but iOS has an Arabic keyboard which I can get by General->International->Add Keyboard option. I'm only trying to get that keyboard to come up programmatically, like it comes up in Simulator.